# Spring Pagination HttpMessageNotWritableException HTTP Status 500

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-status-codes, http-status-code-500

Controller:

I return here as the result is ok.

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET , value = "/pagination")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get By Pagination Operation", response = ProjectDto.class)
    public ResponseEntity<TPage<ProjectDto>> getAllByPagination(Pageable pageable) {
        TPage<ProjectDto> data =projectService.getAllPageable(pageable);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(data);
    }
```

Repository:

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> {

    Project getByProjectCode(String projectCode);
    List<Project> getByProjectCodeContains(String projectCode);
    Project getByProjectCodeAndIdNot(String projectCode, Long id);
    Page<Project> findAll (Pageable pageable);
    List<Project> findAll (Sort sort);
}
```

ProjectDTO:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@ApiModel(value = "Project Data Transfer Object")
public class ProjectDto {
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Project ID ")
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "Name Of Project.")
    private String projectName;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "Code Of Project.")
    private String projectCode;
}
```

My TPage:
I use my own TPage so that all information is not visible.

```
public class TPage<T> {
    private int number;
    private int size;
    private Sort sort;
    private int totalPages;
    private Long totalElements;
    private List<T> content;

    public void setStat(Page page, List<T> list) {
        this.number = page.getNumber();
        this.size = page.getSize();
        this.sort = page.getSort();
        this.totalPages = page.getTotalPages();
        this.totalElements = page.getTotalElements();
        this.content = list;
    }

}
```

ProjectServiceImpl:

```
@Override
public TPage<ProjectDto> getAllPageable(Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Project> data = projectRepository.findAll(pageable);
    TPage<ProjectDto> response = new TPage<ProjectDto>();
    response.setStat(data, Arrays.asList(modelMapper.map(data.getContent(), ProjectDto[].class)));
    return response;
}
```

pom.xml Dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I make the HTTP GET request to the url that mapped with the controller, the error log below appeared.

```
2019-10-15 18:16:44.237 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/project/pagination?page=1&size=3", parameters={masked}
2019-10-15 18:16:44.237 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.util.TPage<com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.dto.ProjectDto>> com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.controller.ProjectController.getAllByPagination(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
2019-10-15 18:16:44.238 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
2019-10-15 18:16:44.238 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2019-10-15 18:16:44.238 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.q.c.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl       : Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from Project as generatedAlias0
2019-10-15 18:16:44.239 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select project0_.id as id1_2_, project0_.created_at as created_2_2_, project0_.created_by as created_3_2_, project0_.status as status4_2_, project0_.updated_by as updated_5_2_, project0_.updated_at as updated_6_2_, project0_.manager_user_id as manager_9_2_, project0_.project_code as project_7_2_, project0_.project_name as project_8_2_ from project project0_ limit ? offset ?
Hibernate: select project0_.id as id1_2_, project0_.created_at as created_2_2_, project0_.created_by as created_3_2_, project0_.status as status4_2_, project0_.updated_by as updated_5_2_, project0_.updated_at as updated_6_2_, project0_.manager_user_id as manager_9_2_, project0_.project_code as project_7_2_, project0_.project_name as project_8_2_ from project project0_ limit ? offset ?
2019-10-15 18:16:44.239 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.model.Project#4]
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 1
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.model.Project#5]
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 2
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.model.Project#6]
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving associations for [com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.model.Project#4]
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.model.Project#4]
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving associations for [com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.model.Project#5]
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.model.Project#5]
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving associations for [com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.model.Project#6]
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.model.Project#6]
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.q.c.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl       : Rendered criteria query -> select count(generatedAlias0) from Project as generatedAlias0
2019-10-15 18:16:44.240 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(project0_.id) as col_0_0_ from project project0_
Hibernate: select count(project0_.id) as col_0_0_ from project project0_
2019-10-15 18:16:44.241 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
2019-10-15 18:16:44.241 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: 
2019-10-15 18:16:44.241 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
2019-10-15 18:16:44.243 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
2019-10-15 18:16:44.244 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : No match for [*/*], supported: []
2019-10-15 18:16:44.244 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.basarsoft.issuemanagement.util.TPage]
2019-10-15 18:16:44.244 DEBUG 2296 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

I wonder if I forgot any configuration in my project.

Comment: Do your TPage class has setters and getters??

Comment: I forgot to add. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did it worked after adding setters and getters

Comment: Yes it is worked. Thanks a lot.